# Troubles including Swiftmailer file after installation with composer

Tags: php, composer-php, swiftmailer

I'm a newbie using composer and I'm having some troubles including Swiftmailer files in my public php page after installation.
I installed Swiftmailer with composer using this instruction:

```
php composer.phar require swiftmailer/swiftmailer @stable
```

All works fine and file are installed in

```
./vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/
```

Since files are in the root and not in public_html, I'm not able to include them in order to start using it.

Did I do a mistake installing Swiftmailer in that position?
Do I need to change it?
If so is there a quick way?

Comment: How do you use swiftmailer? Do you have a service container ?

Comment: I'm not able to use it, since files are in the root and I don't know which path to use in php in order to include Swiftmailer files in my php page. I don't know what is a service container

Comment: $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer();  ?

Comment: I think that the first step is this http://swiftmailer.org/docs/including-the-files.html  but i haven't the /path/to/  swift-mailer since files are in the root. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: add the following line `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` in your application bootstrap (unless it's already there).

You can simply include this file and you will get autoloading for free.
Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

---

Long Version:

Swiftermailer adds the `lib/swift_required.php` file to the Composer Autoloader:

See https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/composer.json#L25

This file requires some other Swiftmailer files and registers the Swiftmailer Autoloader.

The execution flow should be something like this:

- your application index.php
- your bootstrap.php
- require Composer Autoloader
- files in the `autoload` section are loaded on every request, like `swiftmailer_required.php`
- Now you can use `$mailer = new \Swift_Mailer();`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use stuff that got installed by Composer, you have to include the autoloader in your code.

And because including PHP code uses the filesystem, not the web server access, it doesn't matter where the script is located in terms of being able to access it via webserver - which is a good thing, because you don't want every PHP script to be accessed via the web.

You'd have to include the Composer autoloader in one of the first lines of your script, and then can use everything you installed with Composer.

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php'; // adjust the path depending on where your script is located.
```

This might result in something like this:

```
./public_html/index.php:

include '../vendor/autoload.php'; // located in  ./vendor/

$mailer = new \Swift_Mailer();
```